# Place Editable Area and custom control inside the same facet?

Tags: xpages

I am trying to set up some standard custom controls for our department but want to make them fexible too.

Some of these standard resources and controls will be placed in a template.  The controls will be copied into our apps but inheriting the design from the central template, so I would like to make any customizations at the app level through facets.

My custom control in question, is based off of the  app control from the extension library.  It has a single facet for the left column.   What I would like to do is to place an editable area in the left column but also another fixed standard custom control.

So the user programmer would place a "StandardApp" control on their page.  They would see the left column with a facet where they can drop their own contrl and under it see the standard control in the left column.

Is there any way this can be done?

I just can't seem to be able to drop an editable area and a custom control into the same facet.  Or even two editbale areas into the same facet.

Comment: Have you looked at the XPages Application Layouts Library on OpenNTF?

http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPages%20Application%20Layouts%20Library

Comment: Facet can contain only one element, so put Panel/Div there, and then your default content and another Editabele Area (with non conflicting name).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A facet can only contain a single control, but it can be any control... including containers. So if your facet content is a div (or panel, table, section, etc.), that div can then contain both the standardized content and the editable area. This allows you to chain your facets pretty much as deep as you want, and it's a technique I use all the time to do essentially what you're describing: standard left nav content that appears on every page, with a placeholder for each page to include additional custom content.

The only caveat is that only namespaced (xp, xc, xe, etc.) controls can contribute directly to a facet, not passthru. For example, it can't be `<div xp:key="facetLeft" />`, but `<xp:div xp:key="facetLeft" />` would be valid. But that xp:div can then contain anything you want, including passthru.

Comment: Thanks Tim.  I thought about trying this during my trip home on Friday but thnaks for posting to confirm that it is possible.  And I just tried it, it works like a charm.